# Deleting browser cookies(cross-domain)

Tags: php, cookies, drupal, cross-domain

I have login popup on some other site, when user enters valid credentials he is redirected to his dashboard on drupal website. I am able to delete domain cookies successfully, but the browser cookies of the source are not getting deleted and hence again the user is getting redirected to drupal website. I have used `user_cookie_delete` to delete cookies of drupal website

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question well, you can't delete a cookie that come from another website.

No, the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) forbids that. You can only view or set cookies that you set and that are valid for the current URL.